# Cannot mongodump to a single archive

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to dump a `MongoDB` database to an archive. Using the following command as given in [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-archive).

```
sudo mongodump --uri=mongodb://username:password@host:27017/dbname?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=authdb --archive=file.archive
```

But it doesn't dump as expected rather it creates a dump folder with `.json` file for each `collection`, which should be a single archive file as given.

It also shows the following error -

`--archive=file.archive: command not found`

Mongo version -

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
```

Comment: That sounds like the shell is interpreting part of the URL.  Try putting quotation mark around the URI.

Comment: @Joe You may post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem & I figured out the reason it was happening.

The command I was running was

```
 sudo /usr/bin/mongodump --uri=mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@{atlasendpoint}.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority --archive={filename}.archive --gzip 2>&1
```

I was getting the same error as you. I change the shell command by wrapping quotation marks around the URL; this fixed it for me.

```
sudo /usr/bin/mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@{atlasendpoint}.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority" --archive={filename}.archive --gzip 2>&1
```